# Debugging in QtCreator 5 using Mingw+Gdb on Windows?

Tags: c, qt

I have been looking for a solution for hours. I have QTC 5, Mingw and Gdb under Windows7. I can compile and run my project however I have not been able to figure out how to debug and create a debug configuration in QT 5 under Windows. Bear in mind that everything works as it should in this IDE. I am happy with it just that I have not been able to figure out debugging with this particular configuration.

Most tutorials were concerned with CDB or Qt project or in other platforms, or were talking about some tabs or menus that are not available in v5 as far as I can tell.

What is the right way of setting up a debug configuration and running my .exe in a debug environment using QT 5 and Gdb? My project is mostly C and some C++ with no Qt component. I am just using it as an IDE for C/C++.

thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can just hit the Debug button in Qt Creator to debug it?

Comment: Yes, but that does not work for me. There is no debug configuration and it cannot run the compiled exe.

Comment: What exactly is the output of the debug log (windows - views - debugger log) when you press the debug key?